# How to deploy to a specific object key inside an S3 Bucket with the Serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Serverless framework configuration allows:

```
deploymentBucket:
    name: foo
```

However, it always creates a `serverless` object key inside the `foo` bucket. I want to be able to deploy to a different key like `BAR`.

```
deploymentBucket:
    name: foo/BAR # illustration only, doesn't work
```

What are my options here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe Serverless has this functionality.

Your options are

- Raise a GitHub issue and hope someone adds the functionality for you, or
- Write a Serverless plugin that lets you add prefixes to the objects inside the deployment bucket

Answer (score 2):

I found this [sample config file](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/) and it contains a bucket name prefixed by a serverless module path.

```
deploymentBucket:
    name: com.serverless.${self:provider.region}.deploys # Deployment bucket name. Default is generated by the framework
    serverSideEncryption: AES256 # when using server-side encryption
```

This is a complete shot in the dark, but if you want to write to `foo/BAR`, maybe this setting would work for you:

```
name: com.serverless.${self:provider.region}.foo.BAR
```

EDIT:
Does changing the [package name](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/) affect which key the deployment is written to?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is](https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-node-single-page-app-via-cloudfront/serverless.yml) example with putting `index.html`.

I'm not that much familiar with serverless framework, so hope it helps.